# Menu moves to the next line in smaller dimension

Tags: css, html, alignment, text-alignment

Just testing the responsiveness here by resizing the page to much smaller size in chrome but the menu shifts to the next line http://a-s-team.com/shoploop/index.html

I tried in chrome press ctlr and scroll down. You will see the menu moving to the next line. This would happen in most of the mobile browsers. Any way to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean the search going under the logo?

Comment: I think he means literally zooming out. So, for instance, viewing the webpage at 25% size messes up the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of this is  font-size: 12px; Try to to use % insted of px

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix it, unless (trivially) you set the size to like `2%`

Answer (score 0):

This is a far from optimal solution, but it does solve the problem: you could prevent zoom altogether on mobile devices:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/> <!--320-->
```

If you add this to your page and visit it on, say, your iPhone, you can see that you won't be able to zoom.